# Terminal layout is broken when I turn on lsp

Tags: lsp-mode, rust

I use `lsp-mode` when I write code for Rust, C++ with this init.el settings:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  ;; reformat code and add missing (or remove old) imports
  :hook ((rust-mode c++-mode) . lsp)
  :bind ("C-c h" . lsp-describe-thing-at-point)
  :custom
  (lsp-rust-server 'rust-analyzer)
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy")
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-inlay-hints-mode t)
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-server-display-inlay-hints t)
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-display-parameter-hints t)
  (lsp-rust-analyzer-display-chaining-hints t))
```

I had no problem before using lsp, but after I made the above settings, especially after I started using `rust-mode`, the layout of the screen is broken as shown in the attached image. Is this some kind of problem with the emacs settings?

Or is it a bug in `rust-mode` or `lsp-mode`?

[image]

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use, and what is the `TERM` environment variable set to?

Comment: @db48x I use iTerm2 but I also checked with macos's default terminal and came out with the same outcome. As fort the `TERM` setting, it's set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: You are probably setting `TERM` in your shell startup file, which often causes this kind of problem. Emacs thinks it is running in xterm, but actually it is running in iTerm2. Not all terminal emulators have the same control sequences, so eventually Emacs will do something that xterm would have understood but that iTerm2 does not. If you leave `TERM` unset, your terminal emulator will ensure that it has an appropriate value.